# brew update Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable. sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local not working

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo, macos-catalina, chown

I am getting this error:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew update
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew update
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
Password:
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$
```

For some reason, it is not letting me to change the ownership and permissions of `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0):

From High Sierra you cannot change ownership of /usr/local.

Use:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```